# Pyttsx hangs in runAndWait() after speaking on OSX

Tags: python, macos, pyttsx

I have recently look into using Pyttsx in Python 2.7 for a project I'm doing, but after it has finished speaking the program hangs and won't continue.

Here is my code:

```
import pyttsx

engine = pyttsx.init()

engine.say("Hello world.")
engine.runAndWait()
```

After running engine.runAndWait(), it doesn't run anything else and hangs without returning anything. I tried adding a print afterwards, but it didn't print anything.

Is this common for anyone else, and is there a fix for this? If not then is there a good alternative? (Aside from Google TTS)

Thanks!

---------EXTRA--------
I use a Macbook Pro with OS X El Capitan 10.11.4

Answer (score 1):

This is a bug in pyttsx, you have to wait until it is resolved

https://github.com/RapidWareTech/pyttsx/issues/26

Answer (score 1):

To deal with this problem, 
1- make a class for pyttsx3; 
2- make an instance of the class, send the text to it, then del() it. 
3- repeat step 2 several times.

the Class:

```
import pyttsx3

class _TTS:

    engine = None
    rate = None
    def __init__(self):
        self.engine = pyttsx3.init()


    def start(self,text_):
        self.engine.say(text_)
        self.engine.runAndWait()
```

the instance:

```
 tts = _TTS()
 tts.start("text")
 del(tts)
```

Comment: Wow! This actually works. (Running pyttsx3 on MacOS took minutes for `runAndWait` to finish, compared to 1 second per sentence this way.)

Answer (score 0):

This issue has been resolved in pyttsx3.

```
!pip install pyttsx3

import pyttsx3 as p
text = "The issue has been resolved"
p.speak(text)
```