# pyttsx3 engine.runAndWait() causing problem

Tags: python, pyttsx3

I was making personal assistant for myself but faced an error.

```py
def listen():
    with sr.Microphone() as source:
        speak("Listening...")
        r.pause_threshold = 1  
        audio = r.listen(source)
    try:
        speak("Recognizing...")
        query = r.recognize_google(audio, language='en') 
        print(f"User: {query}\n")
        return query
    except sr.UnknownValueError:
        speak("Sorry, I didn't catch that. Can you please repeat?")
        return listen()
    except sr.RequestError:
        speak("Oops! Something went wrong. Please check your internet connection.")
        return None

def speak(text):
    engine.say(text)
    engine.runAndWait()

speak("Hello! How can I assist you today?")
query = listen()
if query:
    running = assistant_logic(query)
```

but my code is only saying "Hello! How can I assist you today?" after that it stops working but I want it to first say ""Hello! How can I assist you today?" and then start listening to user.

Comment: The function engine.runAndWait() is the culprit here. And the issue is with pytssx's integration with M1. And this is around since pytssx 1. [#22](https://github.com/nateshmbhat/pyttsx3/issues/22) and [Stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39183796/pyttsx-hangs-in-runandwait-after-speaking-on-osx). You can use other methods like one explained in this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/76499842/21164393)