# Best text-to-speech module for Python on Mac M1

Tags: python, text-to-speech

I was making a personal assistant which will speak on every response, but the issue is that pyttsx3 and 4 are not working properly.

```py
def listen():
    with sr.Microphone() as source:
        speak("Listening...")
        r.pause_threshold = 1
        audio = r.listen(source)
    try:
        speak("Recognizing...")
        query = r.recognize_google(audio, language='en')
        print(f"User: {query}\n")
        return query
    except sr.UnknownValueError:
        speak("Sorry, I didn't catch that. Can you please repeat?")
        return listen()
    except sr.RequestError:
        speak("Oops! Something went wrong. Please check your internet connection.")
        return None

def speak(text):
    engine.say(text)
    engine.runAndWait()

speak("Hello! How can I assist you today?")
query = listen()
if query:
    running = assistant_logic(query)
```

But my code is only saying "Hello! How can I assist you today?" after that it stops working but I want it to first say ""Hello! How can I assist you today?" and then start listening to user.

Is there another module or API which can help in this case? As pyttsx3 and 4 are not working for Mac M1.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I fixed the above issue using two modules:

1. `gtts` for creating an audio file from text
2. `playsound` to play that audio sound

Here is an example:

First install the modules:

```py
pip3 install gtts playsound
```

Now import them:

```py
from gtts import gTTS
from playsound import playsound
```

Now let’s first create an audio file from text:

```py
language = 'en'
myobj = gTTS(text='Hello World', lang=language, slow=False)
myobj.save("speak.mp3")
```

Now lets play this audio file:

```py
playsound("speak.mp3")
```

Complete code:

```py
from gtts import gTTS
from playsound import playsound

language = 'en'
myobj = gTTS(text='Hello World', lang=language, slow=False)
myobj.save("speak.mp3")

playsound("speak.mp3")
```